# Make Windows 10 PC appear as bluetooth speaker

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth

Is it possible to make my Windows 10 PC appear as a Bluetooth speaker, so I can play the audio from my PS Vita through my PC's speakers?

I've seen a couple of guides on the internet (such as [this one](http://www.guidingtech.com/12120/stream-songs-phone-to-computer-bluetooth/)), but they all seem to require Windows Mobile Device Center, which isn't compatible with Windows 10.

I appreciate I that I could probably achieve the same effect by using a Bluetooth audio bridge, but it would be nice to have one less device on the desk.

Comment: I have seen claims that to make Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Center work in Windows 10 one needs to uninstall (if installed) and then install Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Center 6.1 *for Windows Vista*. Here are download locations for Windows [64-bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3182) and [32-bit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14). I do not know if this works for the latest version of Windows 10.

Comment: What's your bluetooth adaptor, it seems to be driver/stack specific

Comment: I have the same problem. Even Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Center didn't help: it claims the phone is not connected though I connected it via USB and granted access to the phone storage (Galaxy S7). My Bluetooth driver on Win10 is "Inter(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)" version 20.100.5.1 dated April 17th, 2019

Answer (score 5):

With Windows 10 v2004 and later you can go to the Microsoft Store, download the "Bluetooth Audio Receiver" and your PC become a bluetooth speaker...

Comment: Thank you, I used following Bluetooth Audio Receiver at https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N9WCLWDQS5J and it worked.

Comment: Can verify this works. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, Windows has dropped support for it since Windows 8.

Prior to Windows 8, windows came with support to act as an A2DP sink. This meant it could receive high-quality audio streams over Bluetooth.

However, there may be [unofficial means](https://superuser.com/a/1222540/247221) by which to enable A2DP sink support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the project to this pc option? It is in the notification shade(win + a). There is an option called connect. 
Also you can allow project to this pc in settings and it has an option to project audio.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice idea. Although this projects the entire screen, not just audio. It doesn't work on all device combinations, on my laptop and my Android device it doesn't work. :(